# How to convert date stored as string/datetime(both) to only datetime in MongoDB?

Tags: python, mongodb, datetime, nosql, mongodb-compass

I am working on a dataset where a field is stored as either string(**%Y-%m-%d**) or datetime(ISODate Format ex- 2020-05-16T00:00:00.000+00:00). While fetching the same on Python and using $gte/$lte the string type values are getting excluded from the match.

I have tried converting the field to datetime using $dateFromString but since there are values in datetime format, the following error is thrown:
**$dateFromString requires that 'dateString' be a string, found: date with value 2019-05-31T00:00:00.000Z**

Similarly trying to use $dateToString also throws a similar error because of values stored as string in the same field:
**can't convert from BSON type string to Date**.

Also using $toDate throws the following error, which I have no clue about: **Error parsing date string 'Invalid date'; 0: passing a time zone identifier as part of the string is not allowed 'I'; 8: Double timezone specification 'd'; 6: Double timezone specification 'd'**.

Can anyone suggest a solution as I can't seem to find anything to handle this particular issue?

Comment: You can convert the date field value to one type, conditionally, and then compare with input date. Or, compare conditionally based on the field type, but, converting the input date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$toDate` is a convenience wrapper for [$convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/index.html#convert-aggregation)

You could get convert the strings to dates while leaving any values that don't convert properly, like

```
{$convert: {
      input: "$fieldname",
      to: "date",
      onError: "$fieldname",
      onNull: "$fieldname"
}}
```